# Link Progress Bar To Batch File Execution in Install4j

Tags: java, install4j

Can I link a progess bar to install4j's execution of a batch file?

I can execute my batch file or shell file via ProcessBuilder but I'm not sure how to signal progress bar in install4j

**Run Script Step**

```
File installationDir = new File((String)context.getVariable("sys.installationDir"));
File executable = new File(installationDir, "bin/start.sh");
File logFile = new File(installationDir, "autorun.out.log");

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(executable.getAbsolutePath(), 
"-p", (String)context.getVariable("projectsdir"),
"-n", (String)context.getVariable("projectname"));

 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 pb.redirectOutput(logFile);
 pb.directory(installationDir);
 Process p = pb.start();
 p.waitFor();
return (p.exitValue() == 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a progress bar is visible on a screen you can set the progress by calling

```
context.getProgressInterface().setPercentCompleted(...);
```

You need a percent value for that purpose. If you don't have such a value, you can set the progress bar to indeterminate by calling

```
context.getProgressInterface().setIndeterminateProgress(true);
```

Setting the progress is also possible with the "Set the progress bar" action.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, but if I use the Run executable / batch task is there a way to set a call back so I can update the percent completed based on milestones?  I have a log file I could read but I'd need to have one thread handling the batch execution and another updating the bar I guess.  **setIndeterminateProgress** seems a far easier road

Comment: "*is there a way to set a call back so I can update the percent completed based on milestones*" - > No, you would have to write your own action that executes the batch file and reads from stdin in order to determine the progress